# how to choose columns when calculating mean

Tags: python, dataframe, mean

Hi I'm a student learning python.

what's the difference between

```
df.1.mean()
df[1].mean()
```

?

the full code is

```
df= pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10,4)) 
df[1].mean()
```

I'm confused because I used the first method to choose a column in a different data frame before.

Comment: `df.1` is not useful. It results in a syntax error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the name of the column is a string such as "one" then it will work, as df.one is the attribute "one" of the df. Unfortunately the attribute syntax does not work pure integers (numbers) and only can be called by the squared brackets as df[1] where they are handled correctly.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({1:[2,3], 'one':[3,5]})
df.one #works
#df.1 # syntax error
```

Answer (score 1):

For columns that are numbers, it will result in a error if you call `df.1`.

You can use it however for column names that are string.

```
# create new column with string column name
df['new_col'] = np.random.randn()
# get mean 
df.new_col.mean()
```